# About reordering: Why this code throws RuntimeException despite using the volatile?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-memory-model

> ```
> public class ReOrdering implements Runnable {
>     int one, two, three, four, five, six;
>     volatile int volaTile;
>
>     @Override
>     public void run() {
>         one = 1;
>         two = 2;
>         three = 3;
>         volaTile = 92;
>         int x = four;
>         int y = five;
>         int z = six;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The assignments of `one`, `two` and `three` may be reordered, as long as
>   they all happen before the `volatile` write. Similarly, the `x`, `y`, and `z`
>   statements may be reordered as the `volatile` write happens before all
>   of them. The `volatile` operation is often called a *memory barrier*. The
>   happens before guarantee ensures that read and write instructions of
>   `volatile` variables cannot be reordered across a *memory barrier*.
>
> The happens before guarantee has another effect: When a thread writes
>   to a `volatile` variable, then all other variables - including
>   non-volatiles - changed by the thread before writing to the `volatile`
>   variable are also flushed to main memory. When a thread reads a
>   `volatile` variable it also reads all other variables - including
>   non-volatile - that were flushed to main memory together with the
>   `volatile` variable.

© Bruce Eckel "On Java 8"

I must have misunderstood something because this code doesn't work like this

```
public class Reordering {
    private int x;
    private volatile int y;

    public void writer() {
        x = 1;
        y = 2;
    }

    public void reader() {
        if (y == 2) {
            if(x == 0) {
                // X assignment is happens-before for
                // volatile Y assignment
                // so X can't be 0 when Y equals 2
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }

            x = 0;
            y = 0;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Reordering reordering = new Reordering();

        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                reordering.writer();
            }
        });

        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();

        while (true) {
            reordering.reader();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think your example is complicating this by having the 2 threads both write to the same variables, the 2 threads are getting interwoven unpredictably.

Comment: @NathanHughes at first, I can't imagine the execution path which can lead to such a state. At second, how it can be possible to reproduce reordering without more than one thread?

Comment: This is a simple race condition that happens with or without `volatile`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, the problem can occur when the writer tread has just set `x=1`, while the reader is already in the if block (before the variable assignments):

```
reader             writer state
-----------------  ------ --------
stops before x=0          x=1, y=2
                   x=1    x=1, y=2
x=0                       x=0, y=2
y=0                       x=0, y=0
                   y=2    x=0, y=2
reader will throw
```